# How to rename all ltree column data that equals a specific string? postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL 12.0

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html

Given following Table:

```
Create Table IF NOT EXISTS Tree
(
    path          ltree PRIMARY KEY,
    amount BIGINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    added_values double precision DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);
```

With following data:

```
path           | amount     | added_values
---------------+------------+-------------
Tree.Cash      | 20         | 2000 
Tree.Cash.Hans | 20         | 1200 
Tree.Cash.Peter| 10         | 1000 
Tree.Cash.Cash | 30         | 900  
Tree.Cash.asd  | 40         | 1600
```

I want to change all labels that equal 'Cash' with the new value 'Coin'.

Desired results:

```
path           | amount     | added_values
---------------+------------+-------------
Tree.Coin      | 20         | 2000 
Tree.Coin.Hans | 20         | 1200 
Tree.Coin.Peter| 10         | 1000 
Tree.Coin.Coin | 30         | 900  
Tree.Coin.asd  | 40         | 1600
```

Can someone help me out?

Edit: `'Cash'` could appear on another label `'Tree.Cash.Cash'` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `replace()`.  Assuming that `cash` only appears once:

```
update t
    set path = replace(path, '.cash.', '.coin.')
    where path ~ '[.]cash[.]' and
          path not ~ '[.]cash.*[.]cash[.]'  -- no duplicates
```

EDIT:

If you just want to replace the first occurrence, you can use:

```
update t
    set path = regexp_replace(path, '.cash.', '.coin.')
    where path ~ '[.]cash[.]';
```

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention cash could appear on another label 'Tree.Cash.Cash' for example

Comment: Should still work without the duplicate part i guess.

Comment: @Ojav . . . and what should the result be in that case?

Comment: `'Tree.Cash.Cash'` would result in`'Tree.Coin.Coin'` i changed the example above.

Comment: After trying it is giving me 'operator does not exists ltree ~~ unknown'. I added explicit type casts with text2ltree and ltree2text and now it gives me syntax error at position 0

Comment: Okay i have to use ~ Operator instead of like and * instead of %

Comment: @Ojav would you edit your answer in order to provide your final working example?

Comment: @elmazzun . . . I think it should work with `like` for this pattern.

Comment: But `path` is ltree type, `like` would not work without a casting with `ltree2text`; same goes for `replace`, would it work without casting `ltree` to `text`?